# How to get swagger running on localhost?

Tags: localhost, swagger

I have both glassfish and tomcat installed on my PC, and usually I start them by running a web app from Netbeans, it will auto start the server and load that page and open a browser to show it.

Now I'm learning swagger, and downloaded it into my C:\swagger-ui-master

I can see the app by showing : file:///C:/swagger-ui-master/dist/index.html

Seems it's working, but how to run it so that :

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui-master/dist/index.html

would work ?

Do I need to create a web app in Netbeans and copy the files into that project or do I need to manually copy some files [ *.war if any ] into glassfish or tomcat to run it from : http://localhost:8080/...  ?

I seem to miss a link in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Maven project that will build a WAR (see online for examples,  there’s probably a simple web maven archetype as a starter)

Add the webjar dependency to the Maven project as a compile time dependency

```
groupID = org.webjars
artifactId = swagger-ui
version = 2.1.0-M1
```

Add maven-jetty plugin under build plugins (google maven-jetty-plugin for examples on how)

Then you simply need to run maven goal jetty:run and this will start a server based on maven project contents at localhost:8080 … it will by default support the /webjars path and you can navigate the jar file contents just as you would any directory.